# why i am getting an error while calling a function?

Tags: javascript

This is my function

```
const accounts = {
  a: 100,
  b: 0,
  c: 20
};

function getAccount() {
  let accountName = prompt("Enter an account name");
  if (!accounts.hasOwnProperty(accountName)) {
    throw new Error(`No such account: ${accountName}`);
  }
  return accountName;


};
function transfer(from, amount) {
  if (accounts[from] < amount) return;
  accounts[from] -= amount;
  accounts[getAccount()] += amount;
}
```

If i try to call transfer function like this

```
transfer(a,20);
```

i get an error that "a" is not defined but if i can call function this way it works

```
transfer(getAccount(),20);
```

why this one works not the former one ?

Comment: Call it as `transfer(accounts.a,20);` . You don't have variable called `a`.

Comment: `const a = getAccount(); transfer(a,20);` ??

Comment: but getAccount() gives  "a" why can't i directly put "a" while calling the function ?

Comment: Because getAccount returns the _string value_ you input into the prompt, which is something completely different than an actual variable name inside the code itself.

Comment: No variable is called "a" in your code.

Comment: You confuse variable names with strings. Try searching for “difference between variables and strings” :) maybe that might help getting your head around this. It was difficult for me as well when I started to learn programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a string as value instead of an undefined variable `a`.

```
transfer('a', 20);
```

BTW, I added an exception handling.

```js
const accounts = { a: 100, b: 0, c: 20 };

function getAccount() {
    let accountName = prompt("Enter an account name");
    if (!accounts.hasOwnProperty(accountName)) {
        throw new Error(`No such account: ${accountName}`);
    }
    return accountName;
}

function transfer(from, amount) {
    if (accounts[from] < amount) return;
    try {
        accounts[getAccount()] += amount;
        accounts[from] -= amount;         // switch, prevent subtracting if no account
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
    }
}

transfer('a', 20);
console.log(accounts);
```